# Change the background in joomla with css

Tags: html, css, joomla

I make a site in joomla.
In Media folder of joomla, I created the folder: Media/Photos and I placed in there a photo `0.Background.jpg`.

I want to change the background of the default template by inserting in its css file the following code:

```
body{
   background-image: url("media/photos/0.Background.jpg");
   background-size: 100%;
}
```

But it cannot find the `media/photos/0.Background.jpg`, so the background cannot be applied ...

Comment: To start of with make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and don't edit your question to include the word "solved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path given is relative to the folder that your CSS file is in.

So in your example, whatever folder your CSS file is in, you are asking it to look for a folder inside that called media, and then another folder inside that called photos.

I'm assuming your CSS file is in a template folder, and media is in the root?

If so, you just need to add a forward slash before `media`. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to work out what path your media folder is in relation to the folder your CSS file is in, and work to it from there.

So, try this first:

```
body{
   background-image: url("/media/photos/0.Background.jpg"); /* is it media or Media? */
   background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Has that solved the issue, or helped realise what the issue may be?

Comment: My friend thank you for your answer ... I tried it with the first "/" but it didn't work ...... But I solved the problem with this way .... the Media is in the Joomla in the main main .... The solution that worked is that inside the forder of "images" of the template I uploaded the background image and I put the code background-image: url("../images/0.Background.jpg"); This worked .... Thanks anyway for your answer !

Comment: As I understand the joomla media folder is not accessible from the template css file .... It accesses only the images folder in the template folders ....

Comment: You can point to any folder in your public_html folder, you just need to use the right path. Using `../` will bump it back a directory. You can use several of these to go back multiple levels.

Comment: Thanks for your advice my friend ! :)

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer, because just putting 'Solved' at your question won't do anything, and you should remove it if anything.

Comment: ~Just click the grey tick next to my answer.